# I want to increase a variable whenever I click a button in tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

> Hello guys, please I'm using this code and I want it to increase a
> variable named `compteur` when I click in the button, I want it to be increased in the `__init__` function.
>
> but the problem is that this variable stays always to 0

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class MainUi(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("300x400")
        self.geometry("+500+100")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    
        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)




class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(background='white')
        # self.master.configure(background='black')
        self.compteur = 0
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Next", width=7, command = lambda: self.next_clicked())
        button1.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.9)  

        print(self.compteur)

    def next_clicked(self):
        self.compteur += 1
        
app = MainUi()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need a class attribute; you implemented an instance attribute, which you reset to 0 every time you create an instance.  Since you haven't clearly specified your desired functionality, it's hard to find a repair for you.

Comment: Your code does have increased `self.compteur` whenever the `Next` button is clicked.  Better state clear what do you mean by *`"i want it to be increased in the __init__ function"`*.  Note that `__init__()` will be executed only once for each instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not that `self.compteur` is not raised, but that the `print(self.compteur)` statement, which would print the raised value, is placed outside of the `next_clicked(self)` method. This should work:

```
def next_clicked(self):
    self.compteur += 1
    print(self.compteur)
```

Comment: yes it works like this, but i need it to be changed inside the init function because i need to use it in some labels

Comment: `self.compteur += 1` changes the `self.compteur` attribute of objects of the `StartPage` class. In your case, this is `frame`. This, however, does not automatically change labels, for the `text` parameter of which `frame.compteur` has been previously used.

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to increase a variable named compteur when I click in the
> button, I want it to be increased in the **init** function.
>
> yes it works like this, but i need it to be changed inside the init
> function because i need to use it in some labels

The problem can be fixed.

- Add Label widget inside `__init__`  function in `StartPage`
- Add `.configure` for Label widget in `next_clicked` function.

That all.

Code:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
   :
   :
   :

    self.label_counter = ttk.Label(self, width=5)
    self.label_counter.pack()
   :
   :
   :

def next_clicked(self):
    self.compteur += 1
    self.label_counter.configure(text=self.compteur)
    print(self.compteur)
```

Screenshot:

[image]